# Replacing a content of a XML Tag

Tags: ruby, xml

Actually i'm working on a tool for simplify revisions.

So i have a given XML file which have a version field like:

```
<productnumber>MyNumber</productnumber>.
```

My tool asks for a revision number and adds the revision to a Revision_History.xml. Now it should use the given revision number to replace it in the other XML file.

What is the best way to do this job? On that time where i using the tool, i don't know what exactly is "MyNumber".

Is parsing the XML and changing with gsub a good way?

I tried out now:

```
def self.update_productnumber(revnumber, edition, language)
    if File.exist?("#{language}/Article_Info.xml")
      info = "#{language}/Article_Info.xml"
    else
      info = "#{language}/Book_Info.xml"
    end
    f = File.open("#{info}", 'w')
    xml = Nokogiri::XML(f)
    query = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new 'productnumber', xml
    query['productnumber'] = "#{revnumber}"
    query.parent = xml.root
    f.write(xml)
    f.close
  end
```

That one gives me back a empty XML file and that warnings:

```
/home/smanns/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:267:in `eof?': not opened for reading (IOError)
    from /home/smanns/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:267:in `empty_doc?'
    from /home/smanns/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:48:in `parse'
    from /home/smanns/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml.rb:34:in `XML'
```

I now found a solution:

```
def self.replace_productnumber(revision, edition, language)
    puts 'Replacing the productnumber'.color(:yellow)
    if File.exist?("#{language}/Article_Info.xml")
      info = "#{language}/Article_Info.xml"
    else
      info = "#{language}/Book_Info.xml"
    end
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(IO.read(info))
    doc.search('productnumber').each do |node|
      node.content = "#{revision}"
    end
    doc.search('edition').each do |node|
      node.content = "#{edition}"
    end
    IO.write(info, doc.to_xml)
  end
```

Thanks for all helpers.

Comment: And also this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nokogiri-talk/K9ndhI_BBUY) will help you.. :)

Comment: Take a look at the [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#from_a_file) documentation on how to parse through a HTML/XML File